How to authenticate and fetch events from Google Calendar with Firebase and Flutter Web?
As per title, I have a web app built with flutter. I want to authenticate the user with Google and then fetch from the user's Google Calendar the events. I also use Firebase Authentication. I have already configured everything in the cloud console, and I manage to let the user enter in the platform, by doing
Future<void> attemptSilentSignIn({bool andRedirect = true}) async {
  try {
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await googleSignIn.signInSilently();
    if (googleUser != null) {
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

      if (andRedirect) {
        Get.offAllNamed(Routes.calendario);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    logger.e('Errore nel login silenzioso: $error');
  }
}

At this point the user is in the calendar page of my app, but when I try to fetch the Calendar Events it fails because it says that the authenticated client is null
Future _fetchEventi() async {
  logger.i('Getting events from Google Calendar...');
  try {
    // Retrieve an [auth.AuthClient] from the current [GoogleSignIn] instance.
    final AuthClient? client = await _ac.googleSignIn.authenticatedClient();

    if (client == null) {
      throw GoogleException('Authenticated client missing!');
    }

    // ...

    final CalendarApi calendarApi = CalendarApi(client);
    final Events response = await calendarApi.events.list(
      'primary',
      timeMin: timeMin,
      timeMax: timeMax,
    );

    return response.items;
  } on GoogleException catch (_) {
    logger.e('Google Exception');
  } catch (e) {
    logger.e(e);
  }
}

This function ALWAYS throws a GoogleException which is a custom exception I defined. Why the client is null and how to address the problem?
EDIT
I discovered that the authenticatedClient of the extension method checks for an available accessToken (which we know that the signInAnonymously doesn't give). So since the documentation states that this is also a web plugin, what is the purpose of developing an extension method for a platform where it ALWAYS returns null on that platform? I'm really confused!
